# Bootstrap Modal vs Youtube Video z-index Issue

Tags: youtube, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I am using a Twitter Bootstrap Modal and Youtube Video on the same page. I am facing Z-Index Problem where the Video is being displayed above the modal window in Chrome Browser.

How can i solve this issue ?

> http://mink7.com/projects/cmrc/home.html

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The YouTube video you put on your page is flash-based. Flash objects are rendered separately on the top of the window, because they're not the part of HTML5 stack. Z-index has no effect on these.

See e.g. http://www.google.com/search?q=flash+z-index

Comment: You can put the youtube video on your page with the direct object reference (not `<iframe/>` but the `<embed/>` itself) and then add `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` to it. It will possibly help.

Comment: Or, alternatively, it seems that youtube supports setting this attribute in the iframe url; so try to replace your iframe url with `http://www.youtube.com/embed/EBSnWlpTPSk?rel=0&vmode=transparent`. It works in Chrome for me; however, it might not work in some browsers and/or some flash engines.

Comment: tried changing the URL but didn't work. Can you share the embed code. or point me to a link to modify it ?

Comment: Oh sorry, there was a mistype. The correct url is `http://www.youtube.com/embed/EBSnWlpTPSk?rel=0&wmode=transparent`.

Comment: Awesome. works :) could u also share the embed code. so that i will add that just incase :)

Comment: There is an `<embed/>` in the iframe. You may just put this `<embed/>` itself on your page (instead of the iframe that contains it) and add `<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>` to it.

Comment: adding wmode=transparent did not work for me
here is the link to my question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900804/wmode-transparent-for-youtube-video-iframe-not-working-in-ie-with-bootstrap-moda

Answer (score 12):

You should use YouTube urls with ?wmode=transparent param.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EBSnWlpTPSk?wmode=transparent"></iframe>
```

If you include your object/embed tag then you should add `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` for object tags, `wmode=transparent` for embed tags.

Comment: This really helped me. Actually, exactly this post should be marked as an answer, because it solves the problem posted on the question.

Comment: In case you're looking for **JS API [Embedding the YouTube player using SWFObject](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Embedding)** solution (like I was) just add wmode transparent to your params `var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "transparent" };`

Comment: This issue was only happening in Internet Explorer for me, but adding `&wmode=transparent` fixed it for me. The YouTube videos were also showing up over the fixed navbar.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Fatih, solution is to pass `wmode=transparent`. For the IFrame API, I used following:

```
var player = new YT.Player(pContainer, {
            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            videoId: contentID,
            playerVars : {wmode: "transparent"},
            events: {
                ...
                }
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily fix this.

USE:

```
 <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

inside object tag.

```
<object title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390"   
data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EBSnWlpTPSk"  
frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque">  
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

OBJECT method is now deprecated:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters